# Applying Conditional Formatting to Evaluate Each Row in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have two columns of numeric values in Excel. I want to use conditional formatting to highlight the lower number in each row. It's easy when I am just applying to one row, but whenever I try to apply to the two columns, it's highlighting the lower value of the total data set vs. the lower in each row...

I have tried the below:

```
=A1=MIN($A1:$C1)
```

It isn't working.

I've also applied the "Top/Bottom Rule" of highlight the lowest between two cells. My issue is applying it to each row.

EDIT: I had to redo the rows, as the data was not truly numeric. That's fixed, but the above is still not working.

Here's an excerpt of the table:

```
║  Carrier X Cost  ║ Carrier Y Cost ║   
║ 1,200            ║  1,088.56      ║  
║ 2,540            ║  1,882.44      ║  
║ 1,200            ║  847.66        ║  
║ 1,640            ║  1,473.42      ║  
║ 1,100            ║  1,166.98      ║
```

I want the lower number to be automatically highlighted. When I use the formula above it searched the entire data set for the lowest number instead of the lowest number between each row on each column.

Comment: Looks ok, need more details. Are you selecting A1 and down and across?

Comment: A1 must be the active cell when you apply the rule.

Comment: I may have realized a problem... The first row I'm using is NOT a numeric value. It's a text value that is a number (spit out from a formula). I adjusted that and am now comparing two truly numeric columns. The formula above is still not working. I will post an update of that data and what I am trying to get it to look like.

Comment: Shouldn't be like this, kindly correct me if I am wrong. Assuming the data starts from cell `A2` excluding the headers which are placed at cell `A1:B1` then `=MIN(A2:B2)=A2:B2` use this in `CF`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that A1 is the start of your first row (not a header, etc.), and also that you've applied the conditional formatting to the full table of data.

```
=A1=MIN($A1:$C1)
```

and applied to say
`=$A$1:$C$10` works properly for me